# A React Loop was not provided during instantiation

Tags: php, ratchet

i'm trying to use ratchet/React in order to create secure socket in PHP. I've seen a lot of guides and documentation but i still don't kow why this don't work.

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/composer/vendor/autoload.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
use ChatApp\Chat;

require "Chat.php";


$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server('138.68.129.65:8443', $loop);
$webSock = new React\Socket\SecureServer($webSock, $loop, [
    'local_cert'        => 'absolute/path/to/cert.pem', // path to your cert
    'local_pk'          => 'absolute/path/to/to/key.pem', // path to your server private key
    'allow_self_signed' => TRUE, // Allow self signed certs (should be false in production)
    'verify_peer' => FALSE
]);

$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

 $webServer->run();
```

this is the code, the error is in IoServer.php at line 70

```
public function run() {
        if (null === $this->loop) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("A React Loop was not provided during instantiation");
        }

        // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
        $this->loop->run();
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    }
```

i checked if loop was null in my code, but nope

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I've copied the same code from the same [source](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/609#issuecomment-363928589)

After a quick crawling through source code I found that you should add a third parameter to IoServer constructor. So the final working code would be:

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/composer/vendor/autoload.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
use ChatApp\Chat;

require "Chat.php";


$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server('138.68.129.65:8443', $loop);
$webSock = new React\Socket\SecureServer($webSock, $loop, [
    'local_cert'        => 'absolute/path/to/cert.pem', // path to your cert
    'local_pk'          => 'absolute/path/to/to/key.pem', // path to your server private key
    'allow_self_signed' => TRUE, // Allow self signed certs (should be false in production)
    'verify_peer' => FALSE
]);

$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    $webSock,
    $loop /** <--- here is the missing part */
);

 $webServer->run();
```